# What's The Point of Logging Out?

Tags: discussion, support

Don't get me wrong, I love being automatically logging in, but what's the point of logging out unless you log out everywhere?

Comment: There is no point to logging out. Stay here with us. Your so-called "co-workers" and "family members" can wait a little longer. We're your real friends. You can have some more cookies soon.

Comment: Could be worse: [logout fail](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_piXE8lFEABo/TK0Ad3IJnTI/AAAAAAAAAVc/iWRGSW6ANi4/s1600/LogoutFail.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind for me is session fixation.

From [the "Logout Function" section of Wikipedia's "Session Fixation" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation#Logout_function):

> A logout function is useful as it allows users to indicate that a session should not allow further requests. Thus attacks can only be effective while a session is active.

Comment: As soon you you return to SO, it logs you back in and takes more requests...  Are you talking about hacking an in progress session?

Comment: @John - That doesn't happen to me, or if it does I don't notice; it only logs me in automatically if I'm logged in on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I guess it's possible I'm still logged in somewhere.  I open a new browser, go to SE, SO, MSO, and PSE, and all except SE log me in automatically displaying a little "Welcome back John!  You have been logged in."  message at the top of the screen.

Comment: This sounds familiar, but I'm fairly aggressive with cookie clearing, so kaybe that's why I don't have the same experience. Also, you ahould see [@Jeff's comment below about clearing cookies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68417/whats-the-point-of-logging-out/68430#68430).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's currently a fairly serious problem. If I'm logged into any of the SE sites, I get auto-logged into any other one I visit. If I forget to log out of each of them, I'm stuck.

It currently means I can't access SE on a public or shared computer without clearing EVERYTHING. It's a pain.

Comment: just click "log out everywhere" on the logout page and it will clear the HTML5 Local Storage global auth cookie. But yes, you need to do this if you use a shared computer.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - Are you sure about that? I just logged out of meta, using "Log out everywhere" and when I went back to SO and rpg.stackexchange I was still logged in there(s), though when I came back to meta I was not logged in to meta... ?

Comment: @leg HTML5 local storage was cleared; it doesn't clear cookies on each individual site. At the end of browsing you should clear all cookies and cache anyway using the built in browser commands -- or when you begin browsing on a shared computer use Incognito mode.

Comment: @Jeff that's the point though. If I'm using a lightly shared computer where the user doesn't want me to clear all cookies at the end of my session, I'm screwed. If I accidentally don't activate private browsing before starting, I've got a painful cleanup to do, rather than a simple "log out" button.